# different return value len(tuple of tuple) and len(list of list)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to know the length of a tuple of tuple with only one element
`len(((0, 1)))`
but this statement return 2, if I modify to `len(((0, 1),))` then return 1

However `len([[0, 1]])` directly return 1

May I know the difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `len(((0,1)))` you are in fact doing `len((0,1))` which is 2. The outer parenthesis are remove since they are useless . `(...)` could be a math operation with parenthesis (like `(1+3)*2`) or a function call, so the constructor for a one element tuple was define as `(1,)`. So, `len(((0,1),))` will in fact be a tuple with `(0,1)` as his only element.

For `[[]]`, it's a list within a list, so `len([[]])` counts the number of element within the first list, which is one (only `[]`).

Answer (score 0):

It is a one dimensional two dimensional difference.

`len(((0, 1)))` is have two element of tuple return a value of 2.

`len(((0, 1),))` is have two element of tuple but separate by comma(,)

Recognize that there are multiple tuples and return a value of 1.

`len([[0, 1]])` is two dimension list return a value of 1.